# Drawing a ring in OpenCV out of given image

Tags: c++, opencv

So the idea is to take a rectangular image and make a circle out of it. I came up with a simple algorithm that takes pixels from source image and arranges them into cirles row by row, but the problem is that result is too distorted. Is there any algorithm that allows to do that without losing so much data?

Here's the code:

```
//reading source and destination images 
Mat src = imread( "srcImg.jpg", 1 );
Mat dst = imread( "dstImg.jpg", 1 );

int srcH = src.rows; int srcW = src.cols;
int dstH = dst.rows; int dstW = src.cols;

//convert chamber radius to pixels
double alpha;
int r = 250;
double k = 210 / (500 * PI);

//take pixels from source and arrange them into circles
for ( int i = srcH-1; i > 0; i-- ) {
    for ( int j = 1; j <= srcW; j++ ) {
        alpha = (double) ( 2 * PI * (r * k+i) ) / j;
        int x_new = abs( (int) (dstW/2 - (r * k + i) * cos(alpha)) - 200 );
        int y_new = abs( (int) (dstH/2 - (3.5*(r * k + i)  * sin(alpha)))+1000 );
        dst.at<uchar>( x_new, y_new ) = src.at<uchar>( srcH-i, srcW-j );
    }
}

//make dst image grey and show all images
Mat dstGray;
cvtColor(dst, dstGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
imshow("Source", src);
imshow("Result", dstGray);

waitKey();
```

A result is shown below:
[image: result]

Comment: So what you need seems similar to liquify effect with a larger radius, You want to encapsulate the rectangular image in a circular disc of given radius ? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can try the built-in [cv::LinearPolar()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#linearpolar) or [cv::LogPolar()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#logpolar).

But they operate with a full circle, if you need a ring - you can take the [source code for them from GitHub repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp) and tweak it (not as scary as it may sound)